# How do I make a Product Customization Builder

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I need to build a product builder like this one:

http://br.louisvuitton.com/por-br/produtos/speedy-35-mon-monogram-monogram-008941

But I dont even know where I should start. 
Any info will be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you get all the images for variables and create the buttons with HTML. Then use JavaScript to change the images when a button is pressed/hovered over. Go from there.

Comment: I am going to up-vote you only because this question is so bad, there really is not a good answer for it. If there was this would be a good way of doing it. Soon you will be able to comment below questions.

Comment: Thanks man. I would have commented if I could.